# Стилизация маркера элемента списка

Tags: css3, css

1) Каким образом задать отображение маркировки элемента списка справа от содержимого?

2) Каким образом задать стиль маркера элемента списка? - background-color, border, border-radius и т.д. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно попробовать подобный вариант, кроссбраузерность разумеется страдает, но судя по тому что Вам нужен border-radius это уже не так важно )

```
li:after {/*собственно сам маркер*/
        background-color: black;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        color: red;
        content: "$";/*здесь можно в символьном виде задать отображение маркера*/
    }
li {
            list-style-type: none;/*прятаем родные маркеры*/
}
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, спасибо.

Comment: не работает в ие до 9

Comment: согласен, также как и border-radius, css3 однако

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно делал так

```
<style type="text/css">
  .myul { list-style: none; }
  .myul li { display: block; background: transparent url('/img/mylist.gif') right center no-repeat; padding-right: 20px; margin-right: 3px; }
</style>
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <ul class="myul">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

ЗЫ: маркер - не элемент DOM вроде как, а элемент стиля, поэтому border-radius и прочее неприменимо. А картинка еще и понадежнее будет со всякими IE.

Comment: В данном случае стилизуется не маркер, а сам элемент списка.

Comment: А вы где видели тег маркера, чтобы можно было задать ему стиль?

Comment: Я его не видел, потому и поднял этот вопрос.

Comment: Ну так вот) Стилей маркера нет (есть <a href="http://htmlbook.ru/css/list-style-type">типы</a>), а выше вам рабочее решение. Можно вместо `<li>text</li>` вставить что-то вроде `<li><div class="marker"></div>text</li>` и уже с `.myul li .marker` играться.

Answer (score 0):

А чем вам свойство list-style не нравиться?

Например, чтобы поставить маркировку элемента справа можно указать
list-style-position: right;

Сам стиль маркера
list-style

Может я конечно ошибаюсь. Просто это как вариант.

Comment: Там очень ограниченный набор параметров. Больше сделать квадратик, цвет сменить или бордер поставить нельзя, например.

Comment: list-style  -- вот тут можно регулировать переметры.Размер и т.д
list-style-image    --- Меняем квадратик на картинку
list-style-position  -- Позиция маркера
list-style-type   --

Comment: Это же просто маркеры. На мой взгляд много параметров и не должно быть. Если уж сильно хочется сделать супер-пупер список, то проще прибегнуть к другим способам.

Comment: list-style-position: right; - нет такого свойства!  У list-style-position: возможны варианты: inside/outside

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то есть отличное свойство, чтобы подсунуть свою картинку вместо стандартного маркера:

```
li{ list-style-image: url('../image/dot.png'); }
```

И больше ничего не нужно прописывать.